# Android app crashes inside uncaught exception handler (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, unhandled-exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I'm trying to implement an uncaught exception handler in an Android only app built with Xamarin for logging purposes.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (o, e) => exLogger.UncaughtException((Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (o, e) => exLogger.UncaughtException(e.Exception);
```

and

```
 public void UncaughtException(Exception ex)
 {
     try
     {

         Log.Error(TAG, "Exception caught: {0}", ex.Message ?? "Unknown Exception");
         var di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(context.FilesDir.AbsolutePath, TAG));

         //Rest of Handler - saves error to file system, attempts to upload to a server
         ...
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         Log.Error(TAG, "Exception handler failed");
     }
}
```

The handler in question works with zero problems when I implement it in a very simple "Hello World" application, where I trigger an exception on button-press:

```
throw new Exception("this is a test exception");
```

(or similar).

However, When I do the same thing in the application I am actually developing, the app crashes inside the handler, printing no further information as to why this happens.
When I step through my code, the debugger hits a breakpoint at the entry to the handler - e.g. within the `try` block, but before the `Log.Error` line. However, attempting to step further than this point results in immediate app crash, without either the `Log.Debug` line in the try OR catch block being executed - nothing is printed to the ADB Logger. Additionally, the error printed to the ADB Log by `W/system.err` is only the error I intentionally caused (to trigger the handler) - no information on the crash WITHIN the handler is provided.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this crash, or even advice on how to get more information from the  ADB logs on what the crash within the handler was caused by? My only train of thought is that, because my app is a WebView application, potentially the WebView itself is consuming the Exception in some manner? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question, but ANY function call in the handler causes the crash - not just the `Log.Debug` function

Comment: have you ever found a solution for that? i have the same problem. it still crashes the app